# How to run foreach cycle for every ROW in my xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

I use this code to get every `attribute` from `ROW`

```
var dict = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:ROWDATA/ns:ROW", mgr)
                .Attributes()
                .ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value);
            string insertFields = "";
```

Can someone tell me how to make foreach cycle, so it will cycle trought every ROW and fill the dict with the code i posted above.

The xml looks like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.seavus.com/AML/XML-Schema/CTR_Single.xsd">
  <banka>
    <!-- banka children -->
  </banka>
  <METADATA>
    <FIELDS>
      <!-- Fields -->
    </FIELDS>
    <PARAMS LCID="0" />
  </METADATA>
  <ROWDATA>
    <ROW BANK_ID="370" AKTIVNOST_SE_VRSI_VO_19="Г" NAZIV_21="XXXXX" SEDISTE_21="XX" DANOCEN_BROJ_21="12333" BROJ_SMETKA_21="123333" BANKA_21="330" DATUM_22="03.01.2017" CAS_22="13:30" VID_AKTIV_23="XXX" IZNOS_24="12" VALUTA_24="807" DATUM_25="04.01.2017"
      VREME_25="12:55" SIFRA_26="800" OPIS_27="XXXXXXX" />
    <ROW BANK_ID="370" AKTIVNOST_SE_VRSI_VO_19="Г" NAZIV_21="XXXXX" SEDISTE_21="XX" DANOCEN_BROJ_21="12333" BROJ_SMETKA_21="123333" BANKA_21="330" DATUM_22="03.01.2017" CAS_22="13:30" VID_AKTIV_23="XXX" IZNOS_24="12" VALUTA_24="807" DATUM_25="04.01.2017"
      VREME_25="12:55" SIFRA_26="800" OPIS_27="XXXXXXX" />
    <ROW BANK_ID="370" AKTIVNOST_SE_VRSI_VO_19="Г" NAZIV_21="XXXXX" SEDISTE_21="XX" DANOCEN_BROJ_21="12333" BROJ_SMETKA_21="123333" BANKA_21="330" DATUM_22="03.01.2017" CAS_22="13:30" VID_AKTIV_23="XXX" IZNOS_24="12" VALUTA_24="807" DATUM_25="04.01.2017"
      VREME_25="12:55" SIFRA_26="800" OPIS_27="XXXXXXX" />
  </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

Comment: Use `XPathSelectElements` and iterate through them

Comment: if you're going to put all values from all rows into the same dictionary, this will throw an ´ArgumentException´ since, for example, the dictionary key ´AKTIVNOST_SE_VRSI_VO_19´ would be added more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somthing like that?

```
var rows = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ns:ROWDATA/ns:ROW", mgr)
foreach(var row in rows)                   
{
    var attributes = row.Attributes();
    // TODO: some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (XElement row in doc.Descendants().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName == "ROW"))
{
     foreach (var attr in row.Attributes())
     {
          // do something with attr.Name.LocalName, & attr.Value
     }
}
```